# Graylog CSV Export is slow after upgrade

Tags: pfsense, graylog

After I upgraded from graylog version 2.2.1 to 2.4.3, the csv export became quite slow compared to the previous download rate. I have to say that I did many changes

1. putting it behind pfsense
2. using readonlyrest to restrict access and change to secure communication
3. Switching communication to private ips only

I really can't reproduce the problem, as I tried sniffing using Wireshark and tcpdump which both didn't show any irregularities.

Any guidance on how to proceed with debugging this problem is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Hun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find the cause of the slow download rate, as the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` option in `/etc/default/graylog-server` was enabled.